# How can I apply read/write access to a zero-copy-cloned database with restrictive access?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

**Context**

Currently I am working in a setup where the `DEV_DB` is connected to data generated from tests while `PROD_DB` is connected to actual data sources. My goal is to provide a sandbox environment for others to experiment without breaking production functionality, I thought of using Snowflake's infamous [Zero Copy Clone](https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D50Z00009C3VlMSAV/zero-copy-cloning). However, there is a major problem with that. When creating a clone, people who will be using the clone will inherit the same restrictive access on the `PROD_DB` thus making the clone barely useful.

In other words, let's say that on `PROD_DB` user `FOO` is only able to select on MARKETING schema. While user `BAR` is only able to select on the FINANCE schema. Cloning that DB would be restrictive because when testing new features people would want more than to select. At the same time, users should not access data they can't access on prod (even in the clone). So for example user `FOO` shouldn't see data in the FINANCE schema.

**What I have tried to do**

I tried to create a separate SQL script for the CLONE DB that has the same access structure as the `DEV_DB` and apply it to the clone whenever it's created. While this seems viable, I see at least two issues with that. First, I'm using [Snowflake's Terraform provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/chanzuckerberg/snowflake/latest) to manage access, so creating some access with a SQL script and other access with Terraform is not ideal. Second, long SQL scripts that manage access are tough to maintain and to monitor.

**Objective**

I am trying to find a best-practice and a solution in which the following criteria is met:

- Users are able to access a clone of the production database but with less restrictions within the same schema (for example, if the user could only `SELECT` on the `PROD_DB` they should be able to `SELECT` AND `UPDATE` on the clone)
- If a user is not allowed to see data in a schema on the prod DB, they should still not be allowed to see that data on the clone (for example, if a user can't access the MARKETING schema on prod they should still not be able to access it on the clone)

I am happy to share more details, information if needed

Answer (score 0):

if I have understood you correctly, one of your initial statements is incorrect. A cloned object does not inherit any permissions from the object it is cloned from. You have to manually grant the required permissions on the cloned object: [access-control-privileges-for-cloned-objects](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/object-clone.html#access-control-privileges-for-cloned-objects)

However, I'm assuming you're not trying to create Dev DBs in your Production Snowflake account as that would be a really bad approach. As you can only clone within an account, you really should be looking at data sharing or data replication to get data out of your Prod account and into Dev/UAT accounts.

BTW (and obviously depending on where you are located and your local laws) using Production data that contains any PII in a development environment would break all sorts of data protection laws - so you would need to obfuscate your Prod data before you can move it to another location and use it for a different purpose than Production.

Comment: Hi @NickW! In the second paragraph of the link you sent it reads: *”However, if the source object is a database or schema, for child objects contained in the source, the clone replicates all granted privileges on the corresponding child objects”* so to my understanding cloning would work on the database level